# OpenShift Error creating: pods "pod-name" is forbidden: service account was not found

Tags: docker, openshift

I am trying to deploy the Red Hat Single Sign-On container using the following instructions: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_middleware_for_openshift/3/html/red_hat_jboss_sso_for_openshift/get_started. However, when I deploy the container I get the error "Error creating: pods "sso-1-" is forbidden: service account project-name/sso-service-account was not found, retry after the service account is created."

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. In OpenShift web GUI, create project called `project-name`
2. On OpenShift Master, create SSL keystore: `keytool -genkeypair -alias keystore -keyalg RSA -keystore keystore.jks -storepass password`
3. On OpenShift Master, create JGroups keystore: `keytool -genkeypair -alias jgroups -keyalg RSA -keystore jgroups.jceks -storepass password`
4. On OpenShift Master, create secret for RH-SSO: `oc create secret generic sso-app-secret --from-file=keystore.jks --from-file=jgroups.jceks`
5. On OpenShift Master, create the SSO service account: `oc create serviceaccount sso-service-account`
6. On OpenShift Master, add view role to project for SSO service account: `oc policy add-role-to-user view system:serviceaccount:project-name:sso-service-account -n project-name`
7. On OpenShift Master, add secret to SSO service account: `oc secret add sa/sso-service-account secret/sso-app-secret`
8. In OpenShift web GUI, deploy the `sso70-https` with default settings

Comment: did you create service account in right namespace?

Comment: How do I know what namespace "oc create serviceaccount sso-service-account" creates the account under? Do I need to specify project-name/sso-service-account?

Comment: oc create serviceaccount sso-service-account -n namespace

Answer (score 0):

```
oc create serviceaccount sso-service-account -n project-name
```

Make sure to create it in the right namespace using `-n` as stated by @debianmaster

Comment: After performing those steps and attempting to redploy the application I get the error `Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "sso" with ErrImagePull: "unauthorized: authentication required"`

Comment: Are there other logs from around this time?  It seems like the SA is missing its token or the ability to pull images?

Comment: We are thinking that it is the inability to pull images. The user deploying the container is an LDAP user that created the project. We tried deploying the app in the default project, via the CLI, and it worked. In light of this, we ran `oadm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -n project-name -z default` to give any user in project-name the ability to deploy containers. This still doesn't work though.

Comment: The error is unrelated to `scc` as far as I can tell.  How was this project created (`oc create namespace` vs `oc new-project`)?  The default project template makes it so all SA can pull images.  `oc policy add-role-to-user system:image-puller -z default -n project-name` can be used to manually add the permission, but you should not need to do that if you made the project using `oc new-project`.

Comment: I actually made the project in the GUI logged in as the LDAP user. Would that affect anything?

Comment: No that should work correctly.  I am assuming you have not changed the default project template?

Comment: I have not modified any settings related to templates. I followed the Advanced Installation tutorial in the OpenShift 3.5 RH docs and then moved on to the SSO deploy guide form my original post.

Comment: Are you sure what SA is running the pod.  Also confirm that that SA has secrets.  `oc cluster up` may give you an easier environment to test with.